# Mouse event keyboard event mapper

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

I am new in Python and I want to write a script that listens to the left, right or middle(mouse-wheel) button click event. When the left or right mouse button is clicked it should do nothing. In other words, the script should block the left and right mouse clicks.

But when the middle mouse button is clicked the script should press the escape button.

I already found a library for listening to mouse events: Pynput. The problem is that the script have to run on a Windows XP machine so I have to use Python 3.4.4 and I cannot find a version of Pynput for this Python version.

**My question now:** How can I listen to mouse clicks and send keyboard events in Python 3.4.4 for WindowsXP?

**UPDATE:**

Now Pynput is installed correctly and is working. I wrote this:

```
from pynput import mouse
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button == mouse.Button.middle:
        keyboard.press(Key.esc)
        keyboard.release(Key.esc)
        #after pressing the esc-key: stopPropagation(middle mouse click should not be forwarded to windows)
    if button == mouse.Button.left:
        print("left")
        #stopPropagation(left mouse click should not be forwarded to windows)
    if button == mouse.Button.right:
        print("right")
        #stopPropagation(right mouse click should not be forwarded to windows)

# Collect events until released
with mouse.Listener(
        on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

How can I accomplish what I wrote in the # comments? Is it even possible to do such things like prevent the mouse click in windows with Python? Also what I don't understand is when I run the program and I want to quit it (with ctrl+c) I have to press it like 100 times and then it shows this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\path\hello.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pynput-1.3.10-py3.6.egg\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 178, in join
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 1060, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\threading.py", line 1076, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Why? And how can I solve this?

Comment: "I cannot find a version of Pynput for this Python version" - does it not work on your Python version? It's not like library devs must roll a new version of there libs for each new Python version, they're mostly backwards-compatible, so code written in Python 3.1 or whatever should work in Python 3.4 as well.

Comment: @ForceBru I tried to install Pynput on 3.4.4 but it didn't work. I installed it with easy install?

Comment: "Didn't work" doesn't make much sense. What happened exactly? Also, you could try using `pip3` instead of `easy_install`.

Comment: @ForceBru thank you very much now the missing package "six" was installed using pip3. Pynput is now working :)